# Makefile for many LaTeX files and dependencies in increasing order

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following question on writing a reasonable Makefile for compiling a lot of LaTeX exercise sheets for my lectures. The exercises are organised in files `file1.tex`, `file2.tex`, ... `fileXXX.tex` where XXX is the total number (varies from course to course). Now the catch is that I use crossrefs from later files to earlier ones: the dependence of `fileY.tex` is on all the aux-files of the  files `fileZ.tex` with Z < Y: so those have to be generated before.

So instead of hardcoding all the XXX files with their dependencies into a Makefile I'm looking for a more efficient way to do that. It would be somehow nice to specify just the total number XXX of files.

Comment: I think the latexmk would be better than a simple make http://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html

Comment: @uzsolt   Yes, that was my first idea as well. Asked that kind of question on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62142/latexmk-with-external-references but the automatization aspect which I would like to have made this approach rather inconvenient. Hm...?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
N := 100 # can override on the command line, etc.
SRCS := $(foreach n,$(shell seq $(N)),file$(n).tex)

define dep
$(call dep-rec,$1,,)
endef

# $(call dep-rec,.tex files,accumulated aux files)
define dep-rec
$(if $1,$(eval $(word 1,$1): $2)$(call dep-rec,$(wordlist 2,$(words $1),$1),$2 $(call aux-files-of,$(word 1,$1))))
endef

# return the aux files of $1 (which is a .tex file) -- define as appropriate
define aux-files-of
$(basename $1).aux
endef

$(call dep,$(SRCS))
```